# Conditional joins on collections using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoDB, I am trying to achieve the following SQL query on it. but could not find anything useful so far. can anyone tell equivalent mongoose query

```
select * from interviews
inner join candidate on interviews.clientId = candidate._id
inner join billing on appointment._id = billing.appointmentId
where  ('
  interviews.status= "upcoming",
  interviews.startTime= "2017-01-01",
  candidate.clientAgeGroup= "adult",
  candidate.candidatetatus= "new",
  billing.paymentStatus= "paid"
  ')
```

what I got so far is following

```
 const [result, err] = await of(Interview.find({ ...filterQuery }).limit(perPage)
   .skip(perPage * page)
   .sort({
     startTime: 'asc'
   })
   .populate([{ path: 'candidateId', model: 'Candidate', select: 'firstName status avatar' },
   { path: 'billingId', model: 'Billing', select: "status" }]));
```

**UPDATE**

I  have following name and export scheme

```
//interview.model.js => mongodb show name as interview
module.exports = mongoose.model('Interview', interviewSchema);
//candidate.model.js => mongodb show name as candidate
module.exports = mongoose.model('Candidate', candidateSchema);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use filter out objects included in resulting array using `match` but in the case if it couldn't find any, it would still return a null value. So in comparison this works similar to sql left join.

```
const [result, err] = await of(Interview.find({ ...filterQuery }).limit(perPage)
   .skip(perPage * page)
   .sort({
     startTime: 'asc'
   })
   .populate([{ path: 'candidateId', model: 'Candidate', select: 'firstName status avatar', match: {clientAgeGroup: "adult", candidatetatus: "new"} },
   { path: 'billingId', model: 'Billing', select: "status", match: {paymentStatus: "paid"} }]));
```

Also see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions

If you need strictly a inner join then you can use mongodb aggregate pipeline.

```
Interview.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      status: "upcoming",
      startTime: "2017-01-01",
    }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'candidates', // this should be your collection name for candidates.
      'localField': 'candidateId', // there should be an attribute named candidateId in interview model that refer to candidate collection
      'foreignField': '_id',
      'as': 'candidates'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'candidates.clientAgeGroup': "adult",
      'candidates.candidatetatus': "new"
    }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'billing', // this should be your collection name for billing.
      'localField': 'billingId', // there should be an attribute named billingId in interview model that refer to billing collection
      'foreignField': '_id',
      'as': 'billing'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'billing.paymentStatus': "paid"
    }
  },
  { "$sort": { startTime: 1 } },
  { "$limit": perPage },
  { "$skip": perPage * page }
])
```

Comment: @v1sva, thanks for sparing your time to help, I checked the match already before your answer and i'm sure that doesnot help. but I check the lookup query and will get back to you.thanks inadvance

Comment: @v1sva something's not right. I am trying lookup scheme and result iis always empty []. does the name scheme whiich i mentioned in my question, is okay?

Comment: plus i guess youu meant `Interview.aggregate ` instead of `Interview.collection.aggregate`

Comment: I think i am doing something wrong. you're the best. thanks

Comment: happy to help, both `Interview.aggregate` and `Interview.collection.aggregate` should work. But in later case you have to use `toArray()` method to get result. `Interview.collection.aggregate([.....]).toArray().then(data =>`. Also add your interview, candidate, and billing schema as well.